# Netlogo: Using foreach to iterate over two lists filled with variables

Tags: foreach, netlogo

This may be a beginner question, but after using the NetLogo Progamming Guide I'm unable to find a solution...

I am trying to iterate over a pair of lists and conditionally update the values based on a test condition.

[This thread](http://netlogo-users.18673.x6.nabble.com/How-to-insert-variables-into-a-list-td5004556.html) in a Netlogo Forum which gave me the hint to use the LIST primitives reporter but I still can't get the expected output.

Here is a simplified example which describes my problem. 
Please note, that listA and listB are both filled with variables.

```
to test  
 let a1 1
 let a2 5
 let listA (list a1 a2)  
 let b1 6
 let b2 3 
 let listB (list b1 b2)

 (foreach (list listA) (list listb) [ 
  [a b] -> ifelse a < b [set a "a"][set b "b"]])

 show lista
 show listb

end

;expected Output
;observer: [a 5] 
;observer: [6 b]
```

Could someone give me a hint? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi AzraelJe. Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for your question. Please always be sure to concisely describe what your goal is (see the second paragraph I added). Also state how your code is failing ... does it fail to compile? are you getting incorrect output? do you get a run-time error? If an answer is correct then remember to mark it so, or otherwise leave a comment below it if there is a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Lists in NetLogo are immutable- you can't change the values quite like this approach. `map` might be more suitable for this:

```
to test2
  let a1 1
  let a2 5
  let listA (list a1 a2)  
  let b1 6
  let b2 3 
  let listB (list b1 b2)

  show ( map [ [ a b ] -> 
    ifelse-value ( a < b ) [ "a" ] [ a ] ] 
    listA listB ;; pass the lists [ 1 5 ] and [ 6 3 ]
  )
  show ( map [ [ a b ] -> 
    ifelse-value ( a > b ) [ "b" ] [ b ] ] 
    listA listB ;; pass the lists [ 1 5 ] and [ 6 3 ]
  )
end
```

Note that I think your expected output for `lista` should be `["a" 5]` not `["a" 0]`- is that correct?

If you'd like to do this with `foreach` to modify the original lists, I would create an index ( 0 to the length of the list ) to pass to `replace-item`:

```
to test3
  let a1 1
  let a2 5
  let listA (list a1 a2)  
  let b1 6
  let b2 3 
  let listB (list b1 b2)

  let indexer ( range 0 length listA )

  foreach indexer [ ind ->
    let current_a item ind listA
    let current_b item ind listB
    ifelse current_a < current_b [
      set listA replace-item ind listA "a"
    ] [
      set listB replace-item ind listB "b"
    ]
  ]
  print listA
  print listB

end
```